# [Updated details] Searching for 'grails' get "0 results" but I know they are there!

Tags: support, search

I'm searching the site using the search box in the top corner and 'grails' returns nothing.

Using google and 'site:stackoverflow.com grails' gets me some results.

(I know I can use google, but would prefer the search box to work as it's quicker and especially as Jeff was bragging about how sweet the new search was ;) Or am I just doing something wrong?)

Update
OK this is weird...when logged I get 0 results (tried many many times and triple-checked spelling). When I'm not logged in I get the results.

It appears to be restricting to 'bounty' questions.

In my prefs I have "delphi" as an ignore tag, but nothing else. Any ideas?
http://img29.yfrog.com/i/screenhunter02jul301247.gif/

Comment: Check your ignored list, as it probably has `grails` in it.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I don't get anything at all. They do not appear and disappear.

Comment: @Ian: not a dupe, I think it has something to do with the sticky tabs

Comment: Happy to skype, share my screen and show you that I'm not mistaking. Tried this over 20 times and even tried turning it off and on again ;)

Comment: @Kyle, yes I suppose it's a possibility. How about you post a screenshot then Stevo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your [comment here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10915/updated-details-searching-for-grails-get-0-results-but-i-know-they-are-ther/10917#10917) this sounds like when a search is done where the term is a popular tag that it redirects to the tag view. Unfortunately, the tag view (somewhat unintuitively) has "sticky tabs". What this means is that if you were viewing featured questions earlier, you'll be redirected to the featured questions tab, filtered by that tag, causing no results. This would also have the described side effect that logging out fixes it.

Solution: select a different tab

Comment: yeah, seems to be onto something.
I do the search on the 'active' tab, but the search results has the 'featured' tab highlighted.
Selecting 'hot' appears to gotten rid of that sticky issue!
Many thanks Kyle and to all who helped.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're doing it wrong:

This: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=grails

Redirects to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grails

Maybe you searched for [grials](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=grials)?

Or, mayhaps <kbd>grails</kbd> is a tag in your ignored list. You can check it in the Preferences tab of your account. Make sure "Hide ignored tags" is unchecked and/or `grails` is not in your ignore list. Then you should be peachy keen.

**Okay, round 87:** I think you're going to the Featured set, as evidenced by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=grails&sort=featured&pagesize=15). Click on another tab, and see if you get 355 glorious results.

Comment: I'm doing it wrong? LOL :) I only type a word in a box and click search.

Yeah, it's redirecting to bounty questions for some reason - and I guess that's the problem. But if I take the exact same steps with a different word (say 'Rails') it works as expected. :-\

Comment: This thread: o_q O_o O_O ^_^

Comment: I'll second that Eric. 
Voted your answer up as thanks. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Searching for [`grails`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grails) would trigger the tag biased searching, which nets a good amount of 355 at this time.

Something like [`grails running`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=grails+running) also brings back some ORified results, mainly grails. Don't know how they're running though.

Maybe there's a hidden holy keyword prepended to your search requests?

Comment: Clicking on the first link you gave nets me 0 results. :-\
The second link gets me a lot. 
I don't get it.

Comment: Do you even see any number on the right column for how many questions are tagged? If you do, then you have it ignored and hidden.

Comment: The number says '0' when logged in.
When not logged in I get 355.

Answer (score 1):

We added some explanatory text to the blank page when this happens.

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=google-maps&sort=featured

Comment: Reads good well

Comment: Yup, that works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff: That does help explain why there are no search results, but if there *are* questions that come up it can still be confusing why there aren't more (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gmail). Perhaps you shouldn't 'stick' on the featured tab and/or the side bar should say "1 featured question tagged gmail" and not "1 questions tagged gmail"

Comment: Ah good point again Kyle. That's why I thought search was working with 'Ruby' but not with 'Grails'. Ruby was returning some answers but it wouldn't have been all of them, just the bounties.