# SO Tagging Problem?

Tags: support, tags

stackoverflow.com/search?q=tcl lists many questions with the tag Tcl in them.
stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcl say there are no such questions.

Comment: Works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check the tab you're on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10915/updated-details-searching-for-grails-get-0-results-but-i-know-they-are-ther/).

Comment: I was on the featured tab.
that's pretty stupid. The least the system can do is that if there are no questions in the "sticky" tab, then suggest that i search other tabs.
thanks.

Comment: The system/the man should now be showing you that if you're getting zero hits, a reminder that you're on whatever tab you're on and to try another.

Comment: yep, there's a giant <h2> blurb of text explaining this now right smack dab in the middle of the page (try it yourself!), so I don't know what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

I see about 50 questions listed with stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcl.  You might want to check if `tcl` is in your 'ignored tags' list.  If you have 'hide ignored tags' checked in your prefs, they will not show.  What could show when you search for 'tcl' using  `stackoverflow.com/search?q=tcl` are questions and answers that have the string 'tcl' in them, but not necessarily the tag 'tcl'